# How to setup dynamic country, state & city without setTimeout In Crud Modules in Angular2+?

Tags: angular, typescript, timeout, coding-style, observable

Recently I created one CRUD, where along with all details I have 3 specific combos details that I want to let you know: Country, State & City.

While Edit, We want to show details/combos filled with data, so I achieved that with the help of setting timeouts & when my manager saw that he told me that its good practice & part of coding standard to not using timeouts,

now I searched all over the web but I couldn't find any solution for that.
If anyone knows the way, please let me know here in answer.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am sorry, but without your code, I'm not really following what you are saying.  I think I can help, if you are willing to edit your question to include the relevant code samples.

Comment: ok brother, thanks for getting back,
actually i have to check if i am able to share the code or not,
well, i'll share if i am allowed from here.